# Optimization for Pyspark Dataframes code in databricks cluster for String Mapping of Organizations

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes one with 1.8 million records (df2_concat) and another with 16 thousand records (df1_concat).

- df2_concat dataframe has Org Names, address and id
- df1_concat dataframe has facility name address and index.

I need to map them

I have done join in this was

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

pairdDF = df1_concat.join(df2_concat).select(
    [
        "*",
        WRatio_UDF(df1_concat.Facilityname, df2_concat.organization_name).alias(
            "Percentage_org"
        ),
        token_set_ratio_UDF(df1_concat.address_temp, df2_concat.df2_address_temp).alias(
            "Percentage_add"
        ),
        jaro_winkler_UDF(df1_concat.Facilityname, df2_concat.organization_name).alias(
            "Jaro_Org"
        ),
    ]
)

total2DF = pairdDF.where(
    (f.col("Percentage_org") >= 95)
    & (f.col("Percentage_add") >= 95)
    & (f.col("Jaro_Org") >= 0.80)
)

total2DF = total2DF.withColumn(
    "Overall", f.col("Percentage_org") + f.col("Percentage_add")
)

w = Window.partitionBy("ref_id")
total2DF = (
    total2DF.withColumn("maxB", F.max("Overall").over(w))
    .where(F.col("Overall") == F.col("maxB"))
    .withColumn("maxC", F.max("Jaro_Org").over(w))
    .where(F.col("Jaro_Org") == F.col("maxC"))
    .drop("maxB", "maxC")
)


w = Window.partitionBy("ref_id")
total2DF = total2DF.select(
    "ref_id",
    "org_id",
    "Percentage_org",
    "Jaro_Org",
    "Overall",
    f.count("ref_id").over(w).alias("rank"),
)


total2DF = total2DF.withColumn(
    "org_id", when(total2DF.rank > 1, "null").otherwise(total2DF.org_id)
)

total2DF = total2DF.filter((total2DF.org_id != "null"))

# df_new_drop_not_null
tablename = "df_new_drop_not_null"
total2DF.write.format("delta").save("/mnt/delta/" + tablename)
spark.sql(
    "CREATE TABLE rawdata."
    + tablename
    + " USING DELTA LOCATION '/mnt/delta/"
    + tablename
    + "'"
)


total2DF.write.option("header", true).csv(
    "/mnt/curateddatastore/Clinical-Trials/to_process/mapped_aug_28/"
)
```

Its been 4 days still the write option is taking place.
And the output file will be around 2 mb max but still it is taking a lot of time.
Can anyone help me with code suggestion or parallelization or regarding gc etc?

Comment: We do not know your data, we do not know what are doing the UDFs, we do not know your configuration, there is no [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Basically, we have no elements to understand why your code is slow.

Comment: its a data of organizations i need to match from both the set like name, address , place

Comment: I have added changes above please look into it

Comment: Like Steven already commented, please don't use Indian words here. The universal word would be "million", which I assume you also understand.

Comment: I can only advice you to perform a `write` after each transformation to identify the one that create the bottle neck.

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing any condition on your join `df1_concat.join(df2_concat)`, thus spark performs a crossjoin, which is very expensive: for your specific example, you get over 28 billions records at the end of the join.

To change this `join` to a valid inner join, you should add a condition, for instance:

```py
pairdDF = df1_concat.join(
  df2_concat, df1_concat.id ==  df2_concat.index, "inner"
).select(
  ...
)
```

Using this join, you should get at most 16 thousands records instead of 28 billions.

Moreover, as you write two times your final dataframe without caching, you compute this final dataframe twice. You can prevent this by caching this final dataframe, just before write, by adding `.cache()` after the last change on this dataframe as follow:

```py
total2DF = total2DF.filter((total2DF.org_id != "null")).cache()
```